# Escaping HTML while submitting form in PLSQL

Tags: html, forms, plsql, escaping, submit

I have an HTML form rendered by PL/SQL procedure that has an input field for comments to be entered by the user. In case, he enters some script and submits, the same gets inserted into database. To escape it while inserting the data, we can use htf.escape_sc function  (takes care at back-end level). But can we do that for html at front-end level itself? If so, how to proceed?

Comment: What is your concern finally? PLSQL or html at front-end level?

Comment: html at front-end level, how to escape data entered into the comments field before form submission

Comment: exactly the same way as any other data.

Comment: without using js or jquery?

Comment: **NO** client-side code should ever be involved in SQL interaction

Comment: I agree, but before form submission, can't we somehow escape/encode the data being sent so that '<' is received as '&lt;' at server?

Comment: you could shift the task of conversion to the web server, if you absolutely wish to avoid js (btw, why would you?)

Comment: @collapsar because it can be *easily* bypassed?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: _avoiding_ js because it can be easily bypassed ? you will have server-side validation anyway to defend against forged requests, so any client-side adornment only aims at the convenience of the user and maybe at reducing network load or response latency.

Comment: It's a pity but again I face a blob of nice words and proper declarations such as "reducing network load" and "convenience of the user" but which contradicts with real life practice...

Comment: @YourCommonSense: don't know about your life but in mine and in that of my clients these are prominent issues. if you wish to elaborate, i'd suggest to move the discussion to the chat.

Answer (score -1):

you may wish to have a look at validation widgets from some js framework. offhand i remember [`kendoui`](http://docs.kendoui.com) ([kendo ui validator](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/validator)) and [`jqwidgets`](http://www.jqwidgets.com/) ([`jqxValidator`](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxvalidator/jquery-validator-getting-started.htm)). however beware as both toolkits are commercial. [jqueryUI](http://www.jqueryui.com/) should have similar functionality for free, though.

in case you prefer a plain html5 solution have a look at [HTML5 Form Validation / Constraint Validation API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation). There also are [an article on mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation), a list of [Supporting browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation), and of course the [official standard](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/constraints.html#the-constraint-validation-api).

however, **a plain html solution will not perform any conversion** - which means that the user has to enter the data in the way it is expected at the other end, which in your case is probably nothing you'd want to burden the user with ...

ps:
[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/HdSqt/160/) contains an elementary example for validating against a pattern.

disclaimer: i'm not affiliated with any of the named toolkits' producers.

Comment: Thanks collapsar, can this be done without js or jquery, say by html encoding alone? I tried searching for that, but in vain.

Comment: @papashango: see the new section in the answer